# Turn Paragraphs into Unordered List

Tags: php, list, explode

I'm working with Wordpress and I am trying to turn all the paragraphs into an ordered list and it's working almost perfectly.
My code:

```
$list_items1 = explode("<p>", $bulletlist);
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach($list_items1 as $list_item)
        echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
```

The only problem is, that it creates an empty list item at the beginning of each list, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

How can this be fixed? Is there any other solution to fix that? Thanks in advance!
PS: It should also work as an ordered list.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to replace all occurrences of `p>` by `li>`.

```
$list_items = str_replace('p>', 'li>', $bulletlist);
echo '<ul>' . $list_items . '</ul>';
```

The problem with your approach is that `explode('<p>', '<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>')` results in the following array.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(0) ""
  [1]=> string(5) "a</p>"
  [2]=> string(5) "b</p>"
  [3]=> string(5) "c</p>"
}
```

The first element is empty because there is nothing on the left of the first `<p>` tag. As others have suggested there are workarounds like ignoring the first element, but you would still have to deal with leftover `</p>` tags, which mess up your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there may be empty p tags in your wordpress. I would add a conditional to catch empty p tags.

```
$list_items1 = explode("<p>", $bulletlist);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($list_items1 as $list_item) {
    if ($list_item != '') {
        echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

You may want to make the conditional more complex to catch spaces, tabs, or other p tag content you don't want included.

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you provide, there are a few "hacky" solutions you can use to fix this, but it is very hard to give a definite solution based on what is provided. If this is only happening on the first item all the time, you could simply skip the first iteration of the loop like so:

```
$isFirstIteration = true;
$list_items1 = explode("<p>", $bulletlist);
echo '<ul>';
    foreach($list_items1 as $list_item)
    if(!$isFirstIteration){
        echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
    }else{
        $isFirstIteration = false;
        continue;
    }

echo '</ul>';
```

or

you could check if the tag is empty

```
$list_items1 = explode("<p>", $bulletlist);
echo '<ul>';
    foreach($list_items1 as $list_item)
    if(!empty($list_items1)){
        echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
    }

echo '</ul>';
```

Best of luck.